# Fragment with button clicks

Tags: android, android-fragments

Since, i am new to android, i am trying to learn fragments and how they work.I tried to make a length converter app which basically converts `meter` to `centimeters`.Simple, right?

Now I have two portions of the activity,one being the two `edittexts` which are the part of the activity layout, while the other one being the `fragment`.

This fragment basically contains keypad, in short, Numbers and operators displayed on it. Like a normal calci would have.

[image]

[image]

Now i read about the fragment life cycle and how it is supposed to work.

So The first thing that i did was to put everything in `onCreateView` method.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getRootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.calci_keyboard,container,false);
    GridLayout gridLayout=(GridLayout) getRootView.findViewById(R.id.calciKeyboardGrid);
    for(int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++){
        b=(Button)gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
        b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_dark_gradient));
        b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    return getRootView;
}
```

The thing is that, click events work but `edittext` `settext` doesn't seem to work. `Edittexts` are behaving weirdly.

Now, to remove that i thought i am accessing the Activity UI's , so i should do this inside `onActivityCreated` function ,So, i tried this too.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getRootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.calci_keyboard,container,false);

        return getRootView;
    }
     @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View getView=(GridLayout) LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.calci_keyboard,null,false);
            GridLayout gridLayout=(GridLayout) getView.findViewById(R.id.calciKeyboardGrid); // i Logged this obj and it was there
            for(int i=0;i<gridLayout.getChildCount();i++){
                b=(Button)gridLayout.getChildAt(i);
                b.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_dark_gradient));
                b.setOnClickListener(this);
            }
        }
```

When i do things this way i don't seem to get my clicks working?

How am i supposed to do this problem? Can't find any solution.

Go easy on me,Thanks :)

**Below one shows my onClick event:**.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        View focussedChild=getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.calciKeyboardNine:{
                if (focussedChild instanceof EditText) {
                    firstPart=new StringBuilder("");
                    secondPart=new StringBuilder("");
                    EditText editText=(EditText)focussedChild;
                    if(focussedChild.getId()==R.id.lengthConverterFirst){
                       if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(firstPart.toString()))
                           firstPart.replace(0,firstPart.length()-1,editText.getText().toString()+"9");
                       firstPart.append("9");
                       editText.setText(firstPart.toString());
                       editText.setSelection(editText.length());
                       int a=Integer.parseInt(firstPart.toString());
                       a=a*100;
                       editText=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lengthConverterSecond);//second edit text
                       editText.setText(Integer.toString(a));
                       editText.setSelection(editText.length());
                    }else if(focussedChild.getId()==R.id.lengthConverterSecond){
                        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(secondPart.toString()))
                            secondPart.replace(0,secondPart.length()-1,editText.getText().toString()+"9");
                        secondPart.append("9");
                        editText.setText(secondPart.toString());
                        editText.setSelection(editText.length());
                        double a=Integer.parseInt(firstPart.toString());
                        a=a/100;
                        editText=getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lengthConverterFirst);//first edit text
                        editText.setText(Double.toString(a));
                        editText.setSelection(editText.length());

                    }
                }
            }
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*Now, to remove that i thought i am accessing the Activity UI's , so i should do this inside onActivityCreated function ,So, i tried this too* - it didn't work because onActivityCreated() is method of fragment not activity.

try this - just make your edittexts static in activity and then you can access them in fragment by the activity's name like MainActivity.editText(). hope this helps

Comment: i can still access them using `getActivity()` right? 
 
Why would i make them static?

Comment: yes you can access them using getActivity() , but if you make them static then you can access them into another fragments outside the mainActivity

Comment: i dont think that is gonna make any difference